# php post - get null in response HTTP Post

Tags: php, http, post

I have some problems with the $ _POST
I want to get the data that a server sends
The server sends?AdditionalData.cardHolderName=test&additionalData.cardBin=123456

HTTP Post

But I only get "null" in response

```
    $cardBin = $_POST['additionalData.cardBin'];
    $lastdigit = $_POST['additionalData.cardSummary'];
    $cardHolderName = $_POST['additionalData.cardHolderName'];
```

Here is some info on what the server sends
https://docs.adyen.com/developers/api-manual#notificationfields

Comment: Is there anymore of your code that you can share?  Also, have you tried var_dump($_POST) just to see what is being passed?

Comment: Are you sure the form is not submitting a get request and not a post request?

Comment: In your example server sends GET parameters, not POST

Comment: if it really send POST data, you won't see these parameter and value.. Only GET data can be see on the link

Answer (score 1):

Replace post with get:

```
$cardBin = $_GET['additionalData.cardBin'];
$lastdigit = $_GET['additionalData.cardSummary'];
$cardHolderName = $_GET['additionalData.cardHolderName'];
```

Comment: I also get noll with GET

Comment: add var_dump($_GET) and var_dump($_POST) in your code and update your question with what var_dump returns.

Comment: From the api doc, server returns json, you need to use json_decode of variable sent. Wich exactly variable to decode we can say after you provide the var_dump of get / post arrays.